# how do i retrieve data passed thru post in java play

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

this is my code where i need to retrieve data sent in POST:

```
@play.db.jpa.Transactional
public static Result registered(String fullname, String email, String password, String username) {
    if(fullname.isEmpty()){
        return badRequest("<p>fehlerhafte eingabe!</p>").as("text/html");
    } else {
    User user = new User();
        user.fullname = fullname;
        user.email = email;
        user.password = password;
        user.username = username;
        user.save();

    }

    String success = "Successful registered!";
    return ok(register.render(success));

}
```

and this is my user class:

```
public class User extends Model {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String fullname;
@Email
public String email;
@Required(message="Username erforderlich!")
public String username;
@Transient @Required
public String password;

public User(){}

public User(String username, String password, String fullname, String email) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.fullname = fullname;
    }
```

and this is my html:

```
    <form method="post" action="@routes.Application.registered()">
            <p id="login_panel">@success</p>
            fullname: <input type="text" name="fullname" id="fullname" value=""/>
            email: <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value=""/>
            username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username" value=""/>
            password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value=""/>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
   </form>
```

and this is in my routes:

```
POST     /registered                controllers.Application.registered()
```

What is WSRequest? can this be the clue for my problem?

i appreciate any help! thanks thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check the controller class code. You should have all field names as parameter in the called controller method. Then you can use these filed in your application.

Comment: yeah, but the issue is how to get the data which is sent by post. no matter where the method is, i need to catch those passed values.

Comment: sorry for dump question, but do i have to do like this all the time and why cannot i just get the data passed by form without binding it to any class field?

Answer (score 2):

You "registered" action does not need any parameter.

These parameters are provided within the request, and you'll get them by using the [built in form binding](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/JavaForms):

```
public static Result registered(String fullname, String email, String password, String   username) {

    User user =  form(User.class).bindFromRequest().get();
    ....
}
```

Comment: yeah but if i do like this, i am getting this error: 
    `ValidationException: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception`

why is this?

Comment: Please take a look at this: http://blog.sveri.de/2012/04/11/play-2-0-formbind-validation-exception/

Comment: why do i have to do bind the data to class field everytime? why things like this doesnot work: 
``request.get.POST('name');``