# ValidationException: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0

someone got this error before? what is the problem, i cannot figure out the reasons..

my codes are here: [how do i retrieve data passed thru post in java play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11172861/how-do-i-retrieve-data-passed-thru-post-in-java-play/11172909#11172909)

thanks for help in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from  the springbind library that Play is using for the bonding.

You need to add getters and setters in your Java bean.

Please take a look at this: http://blog.sveri.de/2012/04/11/play-2-0-formbind-validation-exception/

Comment: thanks Nico, great help. i will try this now